# can az cli command automatically retry in case of http error 429

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-cli, throttling

I have observed that az command prints http headers only if --debug flag is passed to it.
E.g.

```
az storage account list --debug
```

and headers are printed to stderr and stdout contains nothing.

In case of HTTP 429, too many errors errors, guidance is to retry after interval mentioned in Retry-After response header.

Is there any mechanism that can make az cli automatically retry the API in case of HTTP 429 error?

Edit -- Retries built into az command

```
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/REMOVED/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2019-06-01'): Retry(total=3, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/REMOVED/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2019-06-01'): Retry(total=2, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/REMOVED/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2019-06-01'): Retry(total=1, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
urllib3.util.retry : Incremented Retry for (url='/subscriptions/REMOVED/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2019-06-01'): Retry(total=0, connect=4, read=4, redirect=None, status=None)
```

Comment: Why not `while(!success && retryCount < MaxRetryCount)`?

Comment: I dont think there is, but i dont have any evidence to back it up

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni it would be nice if every caller does not have to do this. Moreover, headers are printed only with --debug option, which prints loads of information and caller has to parse stderr, look for 429, parse Retry-After header and retry.

Comment: I get your point. To the best of my knowledge, as another user said, there is not such in-built functionality for what you are asking. If you try to develop one for yourself you can take inspiration from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.connectionpolicy.retryoptions?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: Looking at stderr, az command does 4 retries via urllib3 retry option. (Updated original post). So the command that usually takes 0.8 seconds, finishes in about 60 seconds, so delay between retries seem to be exponential, but it still does not prevent 429 errors since it does not look at Retry-After header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the responses received so far, answer is "No" and that caller must run az command with --debug option and parse stderr. Here is sample Groovy code.

```
def pat = /'Retry-After': '(\d+)'/
stderr.split("\n").each { line ->
    def m = line =~ pat
    if (m.size() > 0 && m.hasGroup()) {
       retryAfterDuration = Integer.parseInt(m[0][1])
       println("Found Retry-After header, value = ${retryAfterDuration}")
    }
}
```

Here is sample response.

```
                msrest.http_logger : Response status: 429
                msrest.http_logger : Response headers:
                msrest.http_logger :     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Length': '207'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Expires': '-1'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Retry-After': '17'
                msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-request-id': 'c7102dca-4bb1-4d24-8333-0128b8b85b24'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Server': 'Microsoft-Azure-Storage-Resource-Provider/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
                msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads': '11989'
                msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-correlation-request-id': '3a7ba2e1-6908-414b-b162-d6f41dc10521'
                msrest.http_logger :     'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'EASTUS:20200830T234133Z:3a7ba2e1-6908-414b-b162-d6f41dc10521'
                msrest.http_logger :     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Date': 'Sun, 30 Aug 2020 23:41:32 GMT'
                msrest.http_logger :     'Connection': 'close'
                msrest.http_logger : Response content:
                msrest.http_logger : {"error":{"code":"TooManyRequests","message":"The request is being throttled as the limit has been reached for operation type - List_PerHour. For more information, see - https://aka.ms/srpthrottlinglimits"}}
                msrest.exceptions : The request is being throttled as the limit has been reached for operation type - List_PerHour. For more information, see - https://aka.ms/srpthrottlinglimits
```